# Unexpected bitshift results

Tags: c, binary, bit-shift, bit

I'm initializing an unsigned short int with a = 0xff (all bits are set).
Then I assign b to a>>7 which should yield (0000 0001) and it does. However, the odd thing is that when I assign c to a<<7, it isn't equivalent to (1000 0000). I tested this by outputting 0x80 (which is 1000 0000) and c, but they aren't the same.

Here is some code:

```
unsigned short int a = 0xff;
unsigned short int b = a>>7;
unsigned short int c = a<<7; // c should == 0x80
```

I'm unsure what the problem is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. By "output" I mean output 0x80 and c in decimal and hex form.

Comment: but what DO you get when you output c after assigning a<<7 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a short int has 16, not just 8 bits.

So you will likely to get "0111 1111 1000 0000" as the result from 0xff<<7.

Comment: A short could have 8 or 32 bits (even other sizes). int16_t and uint16_t are the only C types that are defined to have 16 bits.

Comment: No, `short` *cannot* be 8 bits.  `short` must have a range of at least `-32767` to `32767`, and `unsigned short` at least `0` to `65535`.  32 bits is OK, though.

Comment: @Liran: Thanks for the link. I was unaware of the minimum size of short. The general idea I was trying to point out was the common misconception that certain types have certain fixed sizes. short == 16 bits is one such misconception.

Answer (score 6):

#### Don't guess at bit types, use `<stdint.h>`

---

A short int *"usually"* has 16 bits. Actually, I'm pretty sure it *always* has 16 except for those Martian computers, but that isn't something the standard promises.

If you want to declare types that have a specific number of bits, the conforming technique is:

```
#include <stdint.h>

  int8_t  a;
 uint8_t  b;
 int16_t  x;
uint16_t  y;
```

Doing this would have avoided your not-completely-right guess at the bit representation of `short`.  For some reason, Microsoft is a long ways from conforming to the C99 standard, even on easy things like `<stdint.h>`. Fortunately, [a project maintains a VC++ stdint version](http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h).

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect that you got 0x7f80.  I think what you meant to write is:

`unsigned short int c =` ***`b`***`<<7; // c should == 0x80`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, VC++ (the C compiler) does not have inttypes.h because it does not fully support C99. You have to use 3rd-party headers (e.g. Paul Hsieh's stdint.h).

Comment: VC++ isn't a C compiler, it's a C++ compiler. C++ compilers don't need to support C99. In an ideal world you should be compiling C with a C compiler, not a C++ compiler, but we unfortunately don't live in an ideal world, so we must sometimes use a jackhammer when all we need is a chisel.

Comment: @Chris: That may be true about Visual C++, but stdint.h can be correctly implemented in 100% valid C++. It doesn't require any C99 functionality. Given that and the fact that versions of the header are available for VC++, there is no good reason to not use it.

Comment: VC is a C compiler as well as a C++ compiler - it's not a C99 compiler, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get that result, you can chop off the portion `a << 7` greater than the 8th-least-significant-bit, using bitwise-and:

```
unsigned short int c = (a << 7) & 0xff;
```